# Turn off marker clustering Google Maps API v3

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, google-maps

All I want to do is turn off clustering for all markers on a map, and I can't seem to find a solution. I'm using the Google Maps for Rails gem.

Comment: bydefault it is false still you can set it to false `"map_options" => {"do_clustering" => false}`

Comment: To add to Sontya comment, you can look at https://github.com/apneadiving/Google-Maps-for-Rails/wiki/Markers for all option for markers